# how to create a database for a PhoneGap android application

Tags: database, cordova

I am new to phonegap.please le me know what is the process for creating database for a phonegap ANDROID project? I AM USING ECLIPSE-JUNO AND CORDOVA 2.3.0.

The code given in phonegap docs is not working...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>Open Database</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is one of the programs i have tried...i get the output whatever is there in d body tag..

**My other doubt is where can we see our data that is inserted in the Database.In Android, we view it with help of SQL LITE MANAGER. Do we have something special for PhoneGap???**

So,Please guide me through this....

Comment: Have you tried browsing through Google or [official doc](http://docs.phonegap.com) ?

Comment: mgpyone,official doc..

    **<html>
    <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    
    function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Open Database</p>
    </body>
    </html>**

this is was one of the programs that i tried.i get whatever is there in the body tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just creating a new SQL Lite Database. Use the Database Object to manipulate the data.

Try this code(from official docs)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }

    // Populate the database 
    //
    function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }

    // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Database</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: manishkumar,yeah thanks..just now i got the output in my emulator as success...
now where can i view the data???

Comment: You can read from the DB.

function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    // Query the success callback
    //
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
        }
    }

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage Check this for complete supported operations.

Comment: hey,thanks!!!......

okay..i think i did not check this properly...even i am on the same page for the past few hours...:P

Comment: manishkumar,i tried there is no answer...the emulator screen is static.....with the text in my body tag...is there any other mistake...i have committed??

Comment: Well the code I mentioned in my answer just writes to the DB. In order to read from the DB you need to include the code that I mentioned in my comment.

function queryDB(tx) { tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB); } // Query the success callback // function querySuccess(tx, results) { var len = results.rows.length; console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found."); for (var i=0; i<len; i++){ console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data = " + results.rows.item(i).data); } }

Comment: hey,i just find in the LogCat as row=0 Id=1. DATA=first row at file:///android_assest/www/index.html....Is this the answer???
**MY EMULATOR SCREEN IS EMPTY**

Comment: Well you need to render the data in your HTML tags to display it.